# Im trying to recover my truecrypt files

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

Hello I have a micro sd card, and on it there are a bunch of files including a truecrypt encrypted volume. I used easus file recovery to get my files back including the truecrypt volume. The problem I have is that when I mount the truecrypt volume which appears successful it wont open although it shows in my computer but says the file is corrupted . Is there any way I can access my files .any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the truecrypt volume recovered by Easus was damaged such that mounting it using truecrypt does not work, you need to recover your files from your backups instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Problem is I dont have a backup for this Truecrypt container at all. Thats why I am trying to recover it. I can mount the container using the password but it just appears as an icon and says its corrupted, I want to find out how I can uncorrupt it so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the actual truecrypt file that "Easus" recovered, with a hex editor. Often recovery programs only get the first few sectors of a file, and the rest could be unrelated data. If it looks significantly different (it has text or HTML or anything not encrypted) then there may not be enough data to recover.

If it does look ok, and truecrypt (or another program like linux's `cryptsetup`) can decrypt / unlock it, then maybe the filesystem is just a little damaged. You might need to use another recovery program to see if it can recover any files from the unlocked truecrypt device.

I'm unfamilar with "Easus", but TestDisk or PhotoRec are usually great. You should try them on the SD card (or it's image) and maybe they'll recover a more complete version of the truecrypt container file.

---

If you had a backup of the SD card, you would have a good copy of the truecrypt file to read, or a backup of it's contents would be great too.

Comment: thanks for that info, Ill try those 2 programs you mention and see what happens. Hopefully I can retrieve all my files.Ive never had this happen before  The thing is , I was going to make a backup onto a disc but didnt get around to it.I know better now anyway

Comment: I just want to say thanks, .I managed to recover all my files using testdisc , worked brilliant ! In the beginning i wasnt too confident that I would get them back , but as soon as I started using it I could see my files again appearing in the window.

Comment: That's good news, you're welcome! It's customary to pick the best / most helpful answer as correct (the green check-mark, or maybe an upvote / up arrow too) as a way of saying thanks.